# Vue: Components/templates as props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am currently trying to learn vue and struggling with the whole component concept.

Let's say I have some components that define tabs(like browser tabs).

This component has a prop called `name`.

So you'd maybe use the component like so:

```html
<tab :name="tab.display_name"></tab>
```

However lets say things need to be a bit more complex. Like for example, you don't just want the name to be a string, but regular HTML. Okay, so, you can use the prop in a `v-html` directive and use the tab component like this:

```html
<tab :name="'<span class=\'fancy-styling\'>' + tab.display_name + '</span>'"></tab>
```

This one took me a while to figure out because of all the quotes. Is there a way to escape this escape hell(pun totally intended)?

How could I take it this out into its own snippet/template?

And what if we make it even more complex - say we require the prop be a vue component?

```html
<tab :name="'<my-custom-component @click="onClick()">' + tab.display_name + '</my-custom-component>'"></tab>
```

The last one is invalid on a number of levels, not the least of which being the mess of quotes.

How would I accomplish this? What is the best approach?

Comment: `<tab :name=\`<span class="fancy-styling">${tab.display_name}</span>\`></tab>` Use ES6 template literals which have been created to solve the escaping and concatenation hell.

Comment: I am using webpack and es6 in general(not sure which preset), and this fails to compile. The following however works: `<tab :name="\`<span class='fancy-styling'>${tab.display_name}</span>\`"></tab>` So I would not say this is escaping any hell, merely delaying the problem.

Comment: Yeah, accidentally removed the outer quotes.

Answer (score 8):

If you are trying to inject html in props, you should really be looking at using slots.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of using components is that you create a separation of concerns. Defining all the layered components in a single line completely defeats that purpose. Create three separate components. One container component like this.

index.vue

```
<template>
    <tab :name="mycoolname"></tab>
</template>
<script>
    import tab from tab.vue
    export default {
        components: {
            tab
        }
</script>
```

The name prop you can than use in that template using {{name}}. Than within the tab component, like this:

tab.vue

```
<template>
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>
    <my-custom-component @click="doStuff()"></my-custom-component>
</template>
<script>
    import my-custom-component from my-custom-component.vue
    export default {
        props: [
            'name'
        ],
        components: {
            my-custom-component
        },
        methods: {
            doStuff () {
                console.log('hooray this totally works')
            }
</script>
```

I am using separate build files here, but the concept remains the same when you just import vue into your project. Components can contain everything, from a simple div with a `<p>` inside to a full page. This component system is insanely powerful to keep things organised.

Without webpack it would look something like this:

```
var myCustomComponent = { 
    template: `fancyHTML`
}

var Tab= {
    components: {
        'my-custom-component': myCustomComponent 
    },
    template: `even more fancy html containing <my-custom-component>`

new Vue({
   el: '#app'
   components: {
      'tab': Tab
    }
})

}
```

Comment: What if the content varies? E.g. you have multiple tabs and sometimes the tab should display your custom component and other times custom html, and other times just a simple name?

Comment: Depends on the amount of flexibility that you need. If there are only so many options you could do something with creating a component for a certain tab and working with some combination of v-if or v-for. If you want to keep full flexibility or inject the html via props use slots as @zom suggested.